# No configuration folder after RCP product export

Tags: eclipse-rcp

Unfortunately there is no 'configuration'-folder and no '.log'-file after exporting an eclipse RCP product.

I can start the product via 'Launch an Eclipse Application' in the 'Product Configuration Editor' without any problems.
I would like to export the product with the 'Eclipse Product Export Wizard' and a 'XXX.product-file'. The folder to which I export is empty and the 'the product includes native launcher artifacts'-flag is set.

Do you know the problem or do you know how to debug this or get the error log?

Many thanks in advance.

For a better understanding the tree of the folder of the exported product is below:

```
.
├── eclipse
│   ├── artifacts.xml
│   ├── p2
│   │   ├── org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core
│   │   │   └── cache
│   │   │       └── artifacts.xml
│   │   └── org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine
│   │       └── profileRegistry
│   │           └── profile.profile
│   │               ├── 1484645239079.profile.gz
│   │               ├── 1484645239543.profile.gz
│   │               ├── 1484645239702.profile.gz
│   │               └── 1484645239707.profile.gz
│   └── plugins
│       ├── bdd_1.0.0.201701171027.jar
│       ├── org.hamcrest.core_1.3.0.v201303031735.jar
│       └── org.junit_4.12.0.v201504281640
│           ├── about_files
│           │   └── cpl-v10.html
│           ├── about.html
│           ├── junit.jar
│           ├── META-INF
│           │   ├── eclipse.inf
│           │   ├── ECLIPSE_.RSA
│           │   ├── ECLIPSE_.SF
│           │   └── MANIFEST.MF
│           └── plugin.properties
└── repository
    ├── artifacts.jar
    ├── binary
    │   └── bdd_root.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.0.0
    ├── content.jar
    └── plugins
        ├── bdd_1.0.0.201701171027.jar
        ├── bdd.klighd_1.0.0.201701171027.jar
        ├── bdd.product_1.0.0.201701171027.jar
        ├── com.google.guava_15.0.0.v201403281430.jar
        ├── com.google.inject_3.0.0.v201605172100.jar
        ├── com.ibm.icu_56.1.0.v201601250100.jar
        ├── de.cau.cs.kieler.klighd_0.11.1.201612080334.jar
        ├── de.cau.cs.kieler.klighd.kgraph_0.1.0.201612080334.jar
        ├── de.cau.cs.kieler.klighd.krendering_0.8.0.201612080334.jar
        ├── de.cau.cs.kieler.klighd.krendering.extensions_0.8.0.201612080334.jar
        ├── de.cau.cs.kieler.klighd.piccolo_0.10.2.201612080334.jar
        ├── de.cau.cs.kieler.klighd.piccolo.freehep_0.3.0.201612080334.jar
        ├── de.cau.cs.kieler.klighd.ui_0.9.2.201612080334.jar
        ├── de.cau.cs.kieler.klighd.ui.contrib3x_0.3.0.201612080334.jar
        ├── de.cau.cs.kieler.klighd.ui.view_0.3.1.201612080334.jar
        ├── editorUnclosableRenderer_1.0.0.201701171027.jar
        ├── edu.umd.cs.piccolo_1.6.0.201612080334.jar
        ├── javax.inject_1.0.0.v20091030.jar
        ├── javax.servlet_3.1.0.v201410161800.jar
        ├── javax.xml_1.3.4.v201005080400.jar
        ├── org.antlr.runtime_3.2.0.v201101311130.jar
        ├── org.apache.ant_1.9.6.v201510161327.jar
        ├── org.apache.batik.css_1.7.0.v201011041433.jar
        ├── org.apache.batik.util_1.7.0.v201011041433.jar
        ├── org.apache.batik.util.gui_1.7.0.v200903091627.jar
        ├── org.apache.commons.cli_1.2.0.v201404270220.jar
        ├── org.apache.commons.jxpath_1.3.0.v200911051830.jar
        ├── org.apache.commons.lang_2.6.0.v201404270220.jar
        ├── org.apache.commons.logging_1.1.1.v201101211721.jar
        ├── org.apache.log4j_1.2.15.v201012070815.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.ant.core_3.4.100.v20160505-0642.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.compare_3.6.0.v20160418-1534.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.compare.core_3.6.0.v20160418-1534.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.core.commands_3.8.0.v20160316-1921.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.core.contenttype_3.5.100.v20160418-1621.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.core.databinding_1.6.0.v20160412-0910.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.core.databinding.beans_1.3.100.v20160509-1025.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable_1.6.0.v20160511-1747.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.core.databinding.property_1.6.0.v20160427-0852.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.core.expressions_3.5.100.v20160418-1621.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.core.filebuffers_3.6.0.v20160503-1849.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.core.filesystem_1.6.0.v20160503-1608.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.core.filesystem.linux.x86_64_1.2.200.v20140124-1940.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.core.jobs_3.8.0.v20160509-0411.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.core.net_1.3.0.v20160418-1534.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.core.net.linux.x86_64_1.2.0.v20160323-1650.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.core.resources_3.11.0.v20160503-1608.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.12.0.v20160606-1342.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.core.variables_3.3.0.v20160419-1720.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.debug.core_3.10.100.v20160419-1720.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.debug.ui_3.11.201.v20160825-1412.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.e4.core.commands_0.11.100.v20160506-0804.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts_1.5.0.v20160504-0909.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.e4.core.di_1.6.1.v20160712-0927.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.e4.core.di.annotations_1.5.0.v20151127-1241.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.e4.core.di.extensions_0.14.0.v20160211-1614.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.e4.core.services_2.0.100.v20160509-1032.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.e4.emf.xpath_0.1.200.v20160506-0804.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings_0.11.100.v20160509-1025.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core_0.12.0.v20160505-1310.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt_0.12.100.v20160517-1505.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme_0.10.100.v20160523-0836.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.e4.ui.di_1.1.100.v20160506-0759.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.workbench_1.2.0.v20160229-1459.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.e4.ui.services_1.2.100.v20160506-0759.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.e4.ui.swt.gtk_1.0.100.v20160301-1001.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.e4.ui.widgets_1.1.100.v20160506-0759.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench_1.4.0.v20160517-1624.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench3_0.13.100.v20160506-0759.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.swt_1.2.100.v20160831-1151.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt_0.14.0.v20160525-0940.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt_0.14.1.v20160829-0832.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.elk.alg.graphviz.dot_0.1.0.201612080903.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.elk.alg.graphviz.layouter_0.1.0.201612080903.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.elk.alg.layered_0.1.0.201612080903.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.elk.core_0.1.0.201612080903.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.elk.core.service_0.1.0.201612080903.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.elk.graph_0.1.0.201612080903.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.emf_2.6.0.v20160526-0356.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.emf.codegen_2.11.0.v20160526-0356.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore_2.12.0.v20160526-0356.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.emf.common_2.12.0.v20160420-0247.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.emf.common.ui_2.11.0.v20160526-0356.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.emf.ecore_2.12.0.v20160420-0247.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.emf.ecore.change_2.11.0.v20160420-0247.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi_2.12.0.v20160420-0247.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.emf.edit_2.12.0.v20160526-0356.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.emf.edit.ui_2.12.0.v20160526-0356.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.runtime_2.9.0.v201605261103.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.emf.mwe.core_1.3.20.v201605261103.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.emf.mwe.utils_1.3.20.v201605261103.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.equinox.app_1.3.400.v20150715-1528.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.equinox.bidi_1.0.0.v20160307-1318.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.equinox.common_3.8.0.v20160509-1230.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.equinox.event_1.3.200.v20160324-1850.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.200.v20160318-1642.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.400.v20160518-1444.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core_2.4.100.v20160419-0834.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine_2.4.100.v20160419-0834.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata_2.3.100.v20160427-2220.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository_1.2.300.v20160419-0834.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository_2.3.200.v20160421-0324.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.equinox.preferences_3.6.1.v20160815-1406.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.equinox.registry_3.6.100.v20160223-2218.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.equinox.security_1.2.200.v20150715-1528.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.1.200.v20160504-1450.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.equinox.util_1.0.500.v20130404-1337.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.help_3.7.0.v20160602-1307.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.jdt.compiler.apt_1.2.100.v20160418-1457.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.jdt.compiler.tool_1.1.100.v20160418-1457.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.jdt.core_3.12.1.v20160829-0950.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.jdt.core.manipulation_1.7.0.v20160419-0705.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.jdt.debug_3.10.1.v20160811-0441.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.jdt.launching_3.8.100.v20160505-0636.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.jdt.ui_3.12.1.v20160822-0645.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.jface_3.12.0.v20160518-1929.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.jface.databinding_1.8.0.v20160420-2231.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.jface.text_3.11.1.v20160819-1517.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring_3.7.0.v20160419-0705.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring_3.8.0.v20160518-1817.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.osgi_3.11.1.v20160708-1632.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state_1.0.200.v20160504-1419.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.osgi.services_3.5.100.v20160504-1419.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.search_3.11.0.v20160519-1501.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.swt_3.105.1.v20160907-0248.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64_3.105.1.v20160907-0248.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.team.core_3.8.0.v20160418-1534.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.team.ui_3.8.0.v20160518-1906.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.text_3.6.0.v20160503-1849.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.ui_3.108.0.v20160518-1929.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.ui.console_3.6.200.v20160518-1858.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.ui.editors_3.10.0.v20160505-0931.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.ui.forms_3.7.0.v20160518-1929.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.ui.ide_3.12.1.v20160823-0925.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.ui.ide.application_1.1.101.v20160829-0827.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.ui.navigator_3.6.100.v20160518-1929.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources_3.5.100.v20160518-1929.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.ui.views_3.8.101.v20160816-1954.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.ui.views.log_1.2.1.v20160829-0826.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.ui.views.properties.tabbed_3.7.0.v20160310-0903.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.ui.workbench_3.108.1.v20160819-2118.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor_3.10.1.v20160818-1626.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.xtend_2.2.0.v201605260315.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.xtend.lib_2.10.0.v201605250459.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.xtend.lib.macro_2.10.0.v201605250459.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.xtend.typesystem.emf_2.2.0.v201605260315.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.xtext_2.10.0.v201605250459.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.xtext.ide_2.10.0.v201605250459.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.xtext.logging_1.2.15.v201605250459.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.xtext.smap_2.10.0.v201605250459.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.xtext.ui_2.10.0.v201605250459.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.xtext.util_2.10.0.v201605250459.jar
        ├── org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.lib_2.10.0.v201605250459.jar
        ├── org.hamcrest.core_1.3.0.v201303031735.jar
        ├── org.junit_4.12.0.v201504281640.jar
        ├── org.objectweb.asm_5.0.1.v201404251740.jar
        ├── org.tukaani.xz_1.3.0.v201308270617.jar
        ├── org.w3c.css.sac_1.3.1.v200903091627.jar
        ├── org.w3c.dom.events_3.0.0.draft20060413_v201105210656.jar
        ├── org.w3c.dom.smil_1.0.1.v200903091627.jar
        └── org.w3c.dom.svg_1.1.0.v201011041433.jar

14 directories, 181 files
```

And here is my product file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?pde version="3.5"?>

<product name="BDDProduct" uid="bdd" id="bdd.product.bdd" application="org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench" useFeatures="false" includeLaunchers="true">

   <configIni use="default">
   </configIni>

   <launcherArgs>
      <programArgs>-nl de
      </programArgs>
      <programArgsLin>-nl de
      </programArgsLin>
      <vmArgsMac>-XstartOnFirstThread -Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
      </vmArgsMac>
   </launcherArgs>

   <windowImages/>

   <launcher name="VisualBDD">
      <solaris/>
      <win useIco="false">
         <bmp/>
      </win>
   </launcher>

   <vm>
      <linux include="false">org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8</linux>
      <windows include="false">org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8</windows>
   </vm>

   <plugins>
      <plugin id="bdd"/>
      <plugin id="bdd.klighd"/>
      <plugin id="bdd.product"/>
      <plugin id="com.google.guava"/>
      <plugin id="com.google.inject"/>
      <plugin id="com.ibm.icu"/>
      <plugin id="de.cau.cs.kieler.klighd"/>
      <plugin id="de.cau.cs.kieler.klighd.kgraph"/>
      <plugin id="de.cau.cs.kieler.klighd.krendering"/>
      <plugin id="de.cau.cs.kieler.klighd.krendering.extensions"/>
      <plugin id="de.cau.cs.kieler.klighd.piccolo"/>
      <plugin id="de.cau.cs.kieler.klighd.piccolo.freehep" fragment="true"/>
      <plugin id="de.cau.cs.kieler.klighd.ui"/>
      <plugin id="de.cau.cs.kieler.klighd.ui.contrib3x"/>
      <plugin id="de.cau.cs.kieler.klighd.ui.view"/>
      <plugin id="editorUnclosableRenderer"/>
      <plugin id="edu.umd.cs.piccolo"/>
      <plugin id="javax.inject"/>
      <plugin id="javax.servlet"/>
      <plugin id="javax.xml"/>
      <plugin id="org.antlr.runtime"/>
      <plugin id="org.apache.ant"/>
      <plugin id="org.apache.batik.css"/>
      <plugin id="org.apache.batik.util"/>
      <plugin id="org.apache.batik.util.gui"/>
      <plugin id="org.apache.commons.cli"/>
      <plugin id="org.apache.commons.jxpath"/>
      <plugin id="org.apache.commons.lang"/>
      <plugin id="org.apache.commons.logging"/>
      <plugin id="org.apache.log4j"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ant.core"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.compare"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.compare.core"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.commands"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.contenttype"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.databinding"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.databinding.beans"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.databinding.property"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.expressions"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.filebuffers"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.filesystem"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.filesystem.linux.x86_64" fragment="true"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.jobs"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.net"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.net.linux.x86_64" fragment="true"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.resources"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.runtime"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.variables"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.debug.core"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.debug.ui"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.core.commands"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.core.di"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.core.di.annotations"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.core.di.extensions"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.core.services"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.emf.xpath"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.di"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.workbench"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.services"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.swt.gtk" fragment="true"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.widgets"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.swt"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench3"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.elk.alg.graphviz.dot"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.elk.alg.graphviz.layouter"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.elk.alg.layered"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.elk.core"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.elk.core.service"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.elk.graph"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.codegen"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.common"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.common.ui"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.ecore"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.ecore.change"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.edit"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.edit.ui"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.mwe.core"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.mwe.utils"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.runtime"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.app"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.bidi"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.common"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.ds"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.event"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.launcher"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64" fragment="true"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.preferences"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.registry"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.security"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.util"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.help"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.jdt.compiler.apt" fragment="true"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.jdt.compiler.tool" fragment="true"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.jdt.core"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.manipulation"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.jdt.debug"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.jdt.launching"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.jdt.ui"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.jface"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.jface.databinding"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.jface.text"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.osgi"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state" fragment="true"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.osgi.services"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.search"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.swt"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64" fragment="true"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.team.core"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.team.ui"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.text"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ui"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ui.console"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ui.editors"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ui.forms"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ui.ide"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ui.ide.application"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ui.navigator"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ui.views"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ui.views.log"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ui.views.properties.tabbed"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ui.workbench"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.xtend"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.xtend.lib"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.xtend.lib.macro"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.xtend.typesystem.emf"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.xtext"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.xtext.ide"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.xtext.logging" fragment="true"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.xtext.smap"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.xtext.ui"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.xtext.util"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.lib"/>
      <plugin id="org.hamcrest.core"/>
      <plugin id="org.junit"/>
      <plugin id="org.objectweb.asm"/>
      <plugin id="org.tukaani.xz"/>
      <plugin id="org.w3c.css.sac"/>
      <plugin id="org.w3c.dom.events"/>
      <plugin id="org.w3c.dom.smil"/>
      <plugin id="org.w3c.dom.svg"/>
   </plugins>

   <configurations>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.commands" autoStart="true" startLevel="3" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.runtime" autoStart="true" startLevel="1" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.common" autoStart="true" startLevel="2" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.ds" autoStart="true" startLevel="2" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.event" autoStart="true" startLevel="2" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator" autoStart="true" startLevel="1" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ui.ide.application" autoStart="true" startLevel="3" />
   </configurations>

   <preferencesInfo>
      <targetfile overwrite="false"/>
   </preferencesInfo>

   <cssInfo>
   </cssInfo>

</product>
```

Comment: How are you doing the export? Are you using a xxx.product file?

Comment: Yes, I would like to export with a xxx.product file and the 'eclipse product export wizard' of it.

Comment: What is your actual question? Have you actually done the export?

Comment: I have done the export and there was no error message. But the folder of the exported product only contains an eclipse and a repository folder. There is no configuration folder, therefore there is no .log file to see the error log. In the eclipse folder is no executable file. Do you know how to export the RCP application successfully?

Answer (score 1):

I had set the flag 'generate p2 repository' in the 'Eclipse Product Export Wizard'. Unsetting this flag made the export successfully.